# Manage multiple redux form on page

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have user data coming from back-end as an array of objects,

```
[{firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'}, {firstname: 'Jane', lastname: 'Doe'}]
```

I am using a redux-form component to render these data.

tried to make the object keys dynamic by binding index to it, but then got unsure how to handle validation, data population etc.

Working code sample can be seen at,

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lake-ln25c

Now changing a field in on 1 form affects the other forms state. like after entering value in one field, all 'clear values' buttons get enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all your forms are actually assigned the same name ([form](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/) property value) when you call `reduxForm`. This property is treated as unique form identifier so that data for specific form can be get from store. According to docs:

> form: string [required]
>
> the name of your form and the key to where your form's state will be
>   mounted under the redux-form reducer

Please note that although you generate unique `formNumber` using `Math.random` you're doing it **only once** in module file (please use `console.log` to see that `formNumber` is generated only once). So all instances of the `UserForm` component are assigned the same name at 'design time'. As a result when you then import form component and render it 3 times all instance use the same name. You can say that from `redux-form` point of view all these 3 form instances are actually the same single form and they use the same data from store.

According to redux-form docs all `reduxForm` config options

> may be passed into reduxForm() at "design time" or passed in as props to your component at runtime.

So solution is to define unique `form` as a component prop at 'runtime' instead of in `reduxForm` config:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="mb-3">Users</h1>
      <hr />
      {userData.map((user, idx) => {
        return <UserForm form={`form-${idx}`} key={`user_${idx}`} data={user} idx={idx} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And of course remove this value from `reduxForm` config:

```
export default reduxForm({
  validate
})(UserForm);
enter code here
```

This way all form instances are independent.

Since now all form instances are independent of each other you don't have to define field names this way:
`` name={`firstName_${idx}`} ``.
You can do it like this:
`name='firstName'`